# Better printing of variables across rails versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puts

Sometimes I work with 5, other times 4 and even 3.

When troubleshooting something, I often do

```
Rails.logger.debug "GREPME #{pp @variable.as_json}"
```

But I never seem to get visually friendly output from this.
Basically I want to be able to see contents of variables formatted in an easy to read fashion, and it should also work with multiple versions of rails, old or new.

Comment: Why not just use byebug and insert a breakpoint?

Comment: "byebug" is not available in most staging/production hosting setups